# Column chart with conditional formatting and positive or negative deviation at the top of the columns in Power BI

Tags: analysis, deviation

I have created the following diagram in Excel: It shows the sales budget per month (gray columns) and the respective overrun or underrun of the actual sales figures per month in green or red within the budget columns. The values for budget and variance are also shown. The line corresponds to the previous year.

[image]

I tried to recreate it in Power BI and created the following diagram.

[image]

I need it to show the positive and negative variances at the top of the columns like in the Excel chart (green for positive deviation and red for negative). In addition, only the budget values and the variance values should be displayed (the small triangle is not necessary, the deviations can be shown as values).

I have tried to format the columns conditionally via the format area, but have not found a solution to my problem, because the positive and negative deviation is within one measure, furthermore I haven't found any possibilty to shift the axis so that both deviations are on top of the columns.
In order to display the necessary values, I have tried to adjust the labels for the entire data.

When I select the labels for the entire data, only the sales budget and the variance to the sales budget are displayed. However, the problem is that the sales budget adds up with the variance  if it is positive. However, I would like to see them displayed separately.

How can I format my columns as required and display the most important values?